# WPF Zoom Control implement MiniMap

Tags: wpf, slider, zooming

I have implemented simple zoom control in my project using Slider control:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,5,5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Name="ZoomIncButton" Content="+" Margin="2" Grid.Row="0" Click="ZoomIncButton_Click"/>
            <Slider x:Name="ZoomCtrl" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1"
                Minimum="0.0" Maximum="8.0" LargeChange="0.15" SmallChange="0.01"  Value="1.0"/>
            <Button Name="ZoomDecButton" Content="-" Margin="2" Grid.Row="2" Click="ZoomDecButton_Click"/>
        </Grid>
```

I would like to implement a minimap which can show where exactly user is on the zoomed UI. I do not want to use any 3rd party controls.

Please let me know if there are any sample/starter code for the same.

Thanks,

RDV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution via this project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85603/A-WPF-custom-control-for-zooming-and-panning

I was looking for some ideas to implement Overview window which are clearly described here.

Thanks,

RDV